# Probability calculation for $\Bbb P(A\cup B)$

Tags: probability

> If $\Bbb P(A\cup B)$ is $0.05$ and events $A$ & $B$ are independent, then what are $\Bbb P(A)$, $\Bbb P(B)$, and $\Bbb P(A \cap B)$

Comment: Have you enough information to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P(A)=x, P(B)=y$. We need to find $x$ and $y$. Writing the equality for $P(A \cup B)$ we have the equation $$x+y-xy=.05.$$Solving we get $x=\frac{.05-y}{1-y}.$ Therefor for any $0\leqslant y \leqslant .05$ we shall have a value of x with $0 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$. We have infinitely many solutions for that. Hope all clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use $\Bbb P(A\cup B)= \Bbb P(A)+\Bbb P(B)-\Bbb P(A\cap B)$

Let $x=\Bbb P(A)$ and $y=\Bbb P(B)$.

Because of independence, $\Bbb P(A\cap B)$ equals what?

Therefore substitution will give you one equation with two unknowns.

...

You can at least find $y$ in terms of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

We see that:

$$\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B) \ \ \ \ \ \mathbf{(1)}$$

Given that events $A$ and $B$ are independent, then:

$$\mathbb{P}(A|B)=\frac {\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)}{\mathbb{P}(B)}=P(A)$$

$$\implies \mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B) \ \ \ \ \ \mathbf{(2)}$$

Substituting relation $\mathbf{(2)}$ into relation $\mathbf{(1)}$ we get:

$$\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)=0.05$$

$$\implies\mathbb{P}(A)=\frac {0.05-\mathbb{P}(B)}{1-\mathbb{P}(B)}$$

Clearly, For $\mathbb{P}(A)\in[0,1]\implies \mathbb{P}(B)\in[0,0.05]$

Also, because:

$$\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)\implies\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)\in[0,0.05]$$

Comment: $\Bbb P(A)\in [0;0.05]$ too.

Comment: Yes, that too. (+1)

Comment: I was thinking on similar lines as you but with two variables one needs two equations to solve the value of 2 unknowns.The second equation that comes to my mind is 1-P(AUB) which is 0.95.Is it possible to solve for x and y using these 2 equations or do  you have an idea for one other equation.

Comment: Keep in mind, $1-\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$ is the compliment to $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$. These two relations are linearly dependent (linear algebra term), and can be obtained from each other. You can try yourself, but that equation won't produce a relation with one unknown, as $1-\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)'-\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)=0$. (Where $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)'$ is the compliment of $\mathbb{P}(A\cup B)$